How to multiple inherit Symfony Bundle Templates within own Bundle
I try to figure out how to get a Bundle Template inheritation/override with Symfony.
I am aware about the Documentation.
Thats´s so far clear and works as expected.
But, I create a own Bundle which inherits as Dependency another Bundle with the goal to extend this.
Bundle A: Toolbox Bundle (Templates located in the Bundle in "templates" Folder and has config as well).
Bundle B: My own Bootstrap Bundle (Templates located in the Bundle in "templates" Folder).
What I do is this:
class BootstrapBundle extends AbstractBundle implements PimcoreBundleInterface, DependentBundleInterface
{
...
    public function loadExtension(array $config, ContainerConfigurator $container, ContainerBuilder $builder): void
    {
        $container->import('../config/services.yaml');
    }

    public static function registerDependentBundles(BundleCollection $collection): void
    {
        $collection->addBundle(new ToolboxBundle);
    }

    public function prependExtension(ContainerConfigurator $container, ContainerBuilder $builder): void
    {
        // prepend config from a file
        $container->import('../config/packages/toolbox.yaml');
    }

...
}

Then I use my "Bootstrap" Bundle within my own Project, and - damn - it ignore the "templates" folder within my own Bundle. Only in my project files if I create a folder for override Templates it works, but it only "overrides" the original Template Path Parts.
My expectation was that Templates will we search in this order:
{current_project_dir}/templates/bundles/BootstrapBundle/...
{current_project_dir}/templates/bundles/ToolboxBundle/...
{vendor_bootstrap_bundle_dir}/templates/bundles/ToolboxBundle/...
{vendor_toolbox_bundle_dir}/templates/...

But it only searches:
{current_project_dir}/templates/bundles/ToolboxBundle/...
{vendor_toolbox_bundle_dir}/templates/...

Looks I made something wrong within my Bundle or it isn´t possible to achive such a inerhitation from Bundle Templates.

It should be possible, but it depends on the procedure behind your DependentBundleInterface which is not described/exposed in your description and it's not part of Symfony. Btw, what Symfony version are you using to achieve this? can you check debug:twig command to know if the bundle's template is properly registered?

Well, you steared me in the right direction. Twig wasn´t aware of that Template location.
I just add in the Bundle Config:
twig:
    paths:
        '%kernel.project_dir%/templates': ~
        'bundles/Bootstrap/templates/bundles/ToolboxBundle': Toolbox

And the path was available now.
Interesting was, that if i use the "prependExtension" method in a Bundle, the DependencyInjection with a load config won´t work. But it´s ok. the "prependExtension" does everything i need at this Bundle.
